# Training job fails in SageMaker if using `torch.compile`

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using SageMaker to train Pytorch ViT model on a single `ml.g4dn.xlarge`. I'm using pytorch version 2.0 and python 3.10.

If I run the training without compiling the model, it finishes without errors.
If I compile the model, the training job fails at the end, after training, with the following error:

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Simplified snippet of the training script:

```
#### Training script ###
model = get_model()

# Adding the next line causes job to fail
# After training is complete
model = torch.compile(model)

# Pytorch lightning
run_training()

#Indicate that training script has completed
print('Training completed!')
```

In both cases, the actual training is completed successfully - `'Training completed!'` is printed, and all the checkpoints and model artifacts are in the S3 buckets they need to be.

Here's the training job's status in case it fails:
[image]

Logs:
[image]

Comment: Are you using Torchvision by chance? If so, what version? I've seen this problem resolved by upgrading Torchvision to >= 0.15.1

Comment: This didn't help. After updating Torchvision to 0.15.1 I get the same error. Can you please explain why you think this should work, or a reference to the similar problem that got solved this way

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to Torchvision >=0.15.1 to resolve this issue.

---

Comment: This didn't help. After updating Torchvision to 0.15.1 I get the same error. Can you please explain why you think this should work, or a reference to the similar problem that got solved this way?